# Creating VS Code Java Project not creating .project or .classpath

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I create a new project in VS Code, I am no longer getting `.project` or `.classpath` files.  Any idea what got messed up?

In VS Code (on Mac) I run command-shift-P and select "Java: Create Java Project".

I'm then presented the choice of "No build tools" or "Maven".

I select "No build tools", select a directory, then provide a project name ("DebuggingLab").  The result is a directory containing `src`, `lib`, and `README.md`, but no `.classpath` or `.project`.

The Readme mentions the "JAVA_DEPENDENCIES" view; but, I don't see that view.  All I see is "Open Editors", "DebuggingLab", "Outline", "Timeline", and "Maven Projects"

Any idea what I did wrong?  I swear that I got `.classpath` and `.project` last week by following the same steps.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found the solution to this.  I had to get something working, so I created a maven project.  That works fine --- although it is more complex than I would like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to install the Eclipse New Java Project to fix it.
(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mellena1.eclipse-new-java-project)